# Webapps just show blank page when deploying on OpenShift

Tags: openshift

As above title, I have a problem. These are steps that I have done:

1. Register a account on Openshift
2. Upload *.war to github with structure (/webapps/*.war)
3. Create new an application with Java, MySQL and phpAdmin and paste the github link
4. Import DB to MySQL
5. Then I go to link *.rhcloud.com and It just show a blank page, nothing to show.

This is the first time I deploy a webpage so I really confuse and dont know what to do. 
Does anybody have done this deploy before? Please show me. Thanks.

This is the screen shot of tomcat log
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and for me the solution was to append my `.war` file name (maven1.war) to the end of the url:

```
http://maven1-maven1.193b.starter-ca-central-1.openshiftapps.com/maven1/
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: FWIW. The original question was about OpenShift V2. You are using OpenShift V3, which is a completely different implementation. How deployments work for the stacks may also not quite be the same.